# How to get a good modularity structuration with Unity/PRISM project

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism, unity-container

I'm trying to create two modular project with `Unity`/`PRISM` based on the same `catalogModule` but with different behaviour.

My problem is I want exactly the same module but my two application have a logon screen(view of my `module1`), my first application launch after logon a view of my `Module2` and  my second application a view of other module. But for obtains this, I included  :

`this.regionManager.TryRequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "View1");`

But with this operation, i no have the exactlty same module1 because my second application need to have :

`this.regionManager.TryRequestNavigate(RegionNames.MainRegion, "View2");`

So i supose i need to create wrapper or other operation. So i can demand you how you proceed when you work with project modularity with PRISM/Unity ?

In advance, thank you for your answers !

Gat